# Assembly - Loop not working as expected

Tags: assembly

I wrote a simple program which finds the minimum number in a set. I am using `0` as a sentinel to signal the exit of the program. My program always selects `0` however as the minimum whenever I type `echo $?` after execution.

```
  1 .section .data
  2 
  3 data_items:
  4         .long 3,67,34,222,45,75,54,34,44,33,22,11,66,0
  5 
  6 .section .text
  7 
  8 .globl _start
  9 
 10 _start:
 11         movl $0, %edi
 12         movl data_items(,%edi, 4), %eax
 13 
 14         movl %eax, %ebx
 15 
 16 start_loop:
 17         cmpl $0, %eax
 18         je loop_exit
 19 
 20         incl %edi
 21         movl data_items(, %edi, 4), %eax
 22 
 23         cmpl %ebx, %eax
 24         jl start_loop
 25 
 26         movl %eax, %ebx
 27         jmp start_loop
 28 
 29 loop_exit:
 30         movl $1, %eax
 31         int $0x80
```

Here, the minimum should be `3` as `0` just serves as a sentinel. How can I fix this error?

Comment: You should post your solution anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
  1 .section .data
  2 
  3 data_items:
  4         .long 3,67,34,222,45,75,54,34,44,33,22,11,66,0
  5 
  6 .section .text
  7 
  8 .globl _start
  9 
 10 _start:
 11         movl $0, %edi
 12         movl data_items(,%edi, 4), %eax
 13 
 14         movl %eax, %ebx
 15 
 16 start_loop:
 17         incl %edi
 18         movl data_items(, %edi, 4), %eax
 19 
 20         cmpl $0, %eax
 21         je loop_exit
 22 
 23         cmpl %ebx, %eax
 24         jge start_loop
 25 
 26         movl %eax, %ebx
 27         jmp start_loop
 28 
 29 loop_exit:
 30         movl $1, %eax
 31         int $0x80
```

I moved the compare with 0 after the increment and change `jl` to `jge`.